# Swap Keys for Game

Tags: games, swap, steam, keys

I want to swap Tab key with Left Shift key for playing Dota 2 from Steam.

I swap the keycodes of the keys and works fine until I start the game. I push Tab (it should be shift to queue actions) but it does nothing and with shift still works.

The more strange fact is that if I open the chat in Dota2 I use Tab like shift and the letters are uppercase!!

Anyone could help me?
Thanks, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is that you are swapping the keycodes for X, but whatever game you are using doesn't use X keymapping. Instead you should use the keymapping from within the game. This usually involves entering a console within the game (e.g. typing ~) and issuing a bind command.
A quick search of Dota commands comes up with :
http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for reply. You are absolutly correct. I keep working on that because it's forbiden changing shift key.